# Whose avatar was saint Jnaneshwar?

Tags: avatars, bhakti

Sant gyaneshwar (dnyaneshwar) was a famous saint from maharastrian bhakti movement (varkari).

Whose avatar was he ?

Comment: No one.What makes you think he is an avatar?  Did you read any statement that he is an incarnation of any God?

Comment: @SwiftPushkar I think some ppl consider him avtar of pandurang(Vitthal). There is arati of Dnyaneshwar (probably by saint tukaram..not sure) in which line appears "Avatar ha Pandurang..." which means "He is an incarnation of Pandurang..".

Comment: @NogShine i hope you got the hint

Answer (score 5):

According to [**Navanath Bhaktisaar (नवनाथ भक्तिसार)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navnath#Navnath_pothi_.2F_Navnath_Bhaktisar)  **Chapter one -Shloka 48**- **Shree Gynashwar was avatara of "Shree Vishnu** " in the form of  Shree Krishna. i.e. Shree Krishna himself incarnated as  Saint Gyaneshwar in Kali-Yuga for the welfare of people.

---

It's said in NavaNath Bhakti Saar that at the end of Dwapar Yuga and starting of Kali Yuga. Shree Vishnu in the form of Shree Krishna called upon  Nine Narayan Rishi's from Swarga Loka and instructed them to take incarnations as NavaNatha for the welfare of people as Kali Yuga is approaching and due it's bad effect on people  . Shree Krishna also told them that ,he himself will incarnate along with them and will be known as Gyaneshwar. i.e. GyanDev which is his other name.

---

Shree Krishna told Nav-Narayanas thus-:

> मी ही प्रत्यक्ष जन्मोन । ज्ञानदेव नामे मिरविन  ।।48।।
>
> Mi he -I myself  ,Pratyaksha - In my real form (i.e. Vishnu) ,
>   Gyanadeve Naame - As the name Gyandev , Miravin - Will proudly roam.
>
> I myself will incarnate as Gyanadeva and I will become famous by this
>   name.

Here we can read  [**NavNath Bhakti saar**](http://navnathbhaktisar.org/adstart.php?no=1)   in (Marathi).

Comment: Nice find yet again. i think you will answer all of OP's similar questions. Btw did u notice that all these Gurus are carrying  red bags on their left shoulders? Are those japa bags or something else?

Comment: Yes , Thank you . Actually I accidentally found about this while trying to write answer about Op's another question about Nine Natha's  - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22486/who-are-the-nathas-of-nath-sampradaya. I will answer that also. :)

Comment: @Rickross - I think the red bags  are "Bhiksha bags " to carry alms  given by the people. It is also possible that the artists painted them in same colour as of their dress. But the actual colour might be different or they were just carrying a piece of cloth and not a actual bag.