# Who are the nAthas of nAth sampradAya?

Tags: tradition, shaivism, nath

One of the largest group of Hindu ascetics is the [Nath (or Natha) sampradaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nath).

Who are the Naths?

Who were the famous 9 Naths?

What is their core ideology?

What sect of Shaivism do they belong to?