# What is the purpose of Navnath?

Tags: scripture, identification-request, kali-yuga, saint, nath

I heard that [Navnath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navnath) are the 9 saints who were born in Kaliyuga. They were so powerful and full of spiritual energy that even Devas were unable to defeat them. Question is, in Kaliyuga, how those great saints can even exist (Since in Kaliyuga it's hard to find such great saints). What's the purpose of existence of those great Sages in Kaliyuga?

Which scriptures talk about Navnaths? And what it says about them?

Comment: http://www.hinduismfacts.org/navnath/ might be useful...

Comment: It is not that highly evolved saints do not exist in Kali Yuga. But they do not interact with the masses so people don't know about them. These saints remain hidden from the public but keep doing good to mankind secretly.

Comment: Related : [who-are-the-nathas-of-nath-sampradaya](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22486/who-are-the-nathas-of-nath-sampradaya)

Comment: @yds Thanks for the link but it don't have even a single comment. Neither I have anything much in my post. I guess concept of Nathas are not much popular in scriptures. Very less are aware of it. That's why both posts are empty.

Comment: @Rishabh If that post had an answer we could close this as duplicate but now only you or moderators can close this... :)